# initialize var with integer : zero == false

Tags: javascript, integer, default-value

How can I initialize correctly my Int variable in JS ?

```js
var h = {
  baz: 0
} // or {} has same result => 42

function foo(opt) {
  opt.baz ||= 42;

  return opt.baz;
}

foo(h);
```

it's because 0 == false is true...

So how can I properly define my variable default value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment):

```js
var h = {baz: 0}

function foo(opt){
  opt.baz ??= 42;

  return opt.baz;
}

console.log(foo(h));
```

**UPD:** in case if you need to handle [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN):

```js
var h = {baz: NaN}

function foo(opt){
  var defaultOpt = { baz: 42 }
  opt.baz = Number.isNaN(opt.baz)
    ? defaultOpt.baz
    : opt.baz ?? defaultOpt.baz;

  return opt.baz;
}

console.log(foo(h));
```

Comment: this not works with NaN :'(

Comment: @Matrix Update with NaN handing just added